# Import table and add incremental primary ID

Tags: sql-server-2008

Is there a way to import a table and at that moment include an incremental primary key

I am importing a flat file, but I would like that SQL Server adds it an incremental primary key.

Is there a way, to avoid doing this:

1. CREATE TEMPORAL TABLE
2. INSERT ALL DATA TO A TEMPORAL TABLE
3. ALTER TEMPORAL TABLE AND ADD IT
   PRIMARY KEY;

I guess doing this costs lots of time...

Comment: simply have an IDENTITY column on your target table.

Comment: so, Is this neccesary????: ALTER TABLE NAMEOFTABLE ADD id INT IDENTITY
CONSTRAINT id PRIMARY KEY; Other way you suggest?

Comment: This would be a **temporary** table that you're using - one that's in use for a temporary period of time. **Temporal** means that the table design takes the time dimension into account (e.g. by having "ValidFrom" / "ValidTo" columns).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
SELECT IDENTITY(int,1,1) AS ID, *
INTO #newtable
FROM dbo.OldTable;
```

But I would recommend investigating your particular problem and probably solving it using the ranking functions.